# Como determinar as users stories?

Tags: arquitetura-de-software, engenharia-de-software, projeto-de-software, gerenciamento-de-projetos, requisitos

Um processo importante no desenvolvimento de software é a organização do que realmente precisa ser desenvolvido e a priorização do que precisa ser feito primeiro. Pelo que tenho visto, uma estratégia para fazer isso é a utilização de user stories.

O que eu tenho achado bastante dificil é determinar essas user stories. Algumas pessoas podem até falar: "isso é bem simples, é só conversar com o usuário final", mas as coisas não são tão fáceis assim. Há casos nos quais o usuário final não quer colaborar de jeito nenhum, diz que não tem tempo para ficar debatendo essas coisas e ainda fica irritado se tentamos aprofundar a discussão sobre o que precisa ser feito.

Além disso, muitas vezes fico em dúvida com relação a granularidade das user stories e vários outros aspectos. Afinal, não basta usar o processo de qualquer jeito, é preciso usar de uma forma que de fato seja útil para o desenvolvimento, de uma forma certa.

O que eu tenho procurado, no caso, é um processo que permita construir as user stories da melhor maneira. Como isso é um procedimento razoavelmente comum, que vejo muitos desenvolvedores utilizando, acredito que deva existir um processo, uma receita, para obter as user stories de maneira correta.

Antes que digam que a pergunta é baseada em opiniões, quero deixar claro que não estou buscando opinião do que um ou outro acha que seja um jeito melhor. Não trato aqui da parte subjetiva, mas sim da parte objetiva baseada em experiência somente. O jeito certo de fazer, que de fato colabora para um desenvolvimento melhor, um processo que baseado na experiência de fato funciona e produz user stories que serão úteis ao final.

Nesse caso, há um processo que permita a obtenção sistemática das users stories para o desenvolvimento de um software?

Comment: Se os usuários que tem conhecimento do dominio não fazem questão de participar do levantamento/validação dos requisitos complica bastante. O jeito é explicar que o desenvolvimento baseado em adivinhção custa bem caro e não da resultados ... o cliente faz questão comprar/pagar por algo que nem sabe o que faz .... Você também explicar que não usar software para resolver o problema é a melhor solução.

Comment: Eu até comecei a responder, mas a resposta ficou... opinativa. :) Acho que a sua pergunta é importante e justa. Mas é difícil de responder. Se existisse uma receita infalível, não haveria tanta discussão e diferentes sugestões de processos e métodos. :/

Comment: Sobre o usuário não colaborar, esses casos costumam decorrer de stakeholders mal informados. Eles pagam pelo que acreditam ser útil, mas jamais conversaram com seus próprios usuários. Quero dizer que o problema foge um pouco da sua alçada (é um problema intrinsecamente institucional), mas nada te impede de atualizar as próprias user stories para tentar servir também como facilitador de comunicação. De fato, eu acredito que métodos ágeis ajudam no sentido de que os usuários tendem a perceber mais cedo quando algo é efetivamente bom e melhora uma atividade.

Comment: @rray "O jeito é explicar que o desenvolvimento baseado em adivinhção custa bem caro e não da resultados". Explicar pra quem? O cara que paga provavelmente já sabe disso. O cara que trabalha só quer... trabalhar. Eu tenho certeza que o problema aí é comunicação, mas não acho que seja entre o cliente e o desenvolvedor. :)

Comment: @LuizVieira, é verdade, acho que esse assunto ficaria melhor de discutir com perguntas menores, talvez um pouco mais objetivas. Até andei pensando em dividir essa pergunta em outras menores, de pontos mais específicos. Esse é um assunto que eu nunca me senti realmente confortável. O que eu estou tentando descobrir atualmente é como sair do zero e chegar em um backlog organizado. Não digo formal, já que eu trabalho sozinho mesmo, mas organizado do ponto de vista de estar claro o que precisa ser desenvolvido.

Comment: Não é uma questão adequadamente classificada como **projeto-de-software** (*software design*). Remover esta marca facilitará a localização de questões.

Answer (score 1):

A "User Story" é baseada no conceito de cartões, ou seja, cada "User Story" é escrita em um cartão contendo o ator (quem quer) a ação (o que ele quer) e a funcionalidade (qual o resultado esperado).

Imagine um cartão, no tamanho padrão de um cartão de visita. Sua "User Story" cabe neste cartão? Se sua resposta foi não, então você precisa dividi-la em outras menores.

Não confunda "User Story" com especificação funcional.

Sobre a dificuldade de extrair as informações necessárias do cliente, isto é papel do PO (Product Owner), que certamente tem experiência como analista de requisitos/sistemas e tem seus meios de "puxar a língua do cliente".

A metodologia Scrum parte do principio que a equipe é pro-eficiente, e isto inclui os stakeholders (cliente).

Para desenvolver um projeto com Scrum, o cliente deve estar ciente de como isto ocorrerá e qual será o papel dele durante o decorrer do mesmo. Um dos pilares do Scrum é: Transparência.

Se o cliente não está receptivo a uma metodologia ágil, talvez você deva procurar outros meios/processos de fazer a gestão de seu projeto.